# Handle Auth User in shopping cart

Tags: php, laravel

I written a code for shopping cart and store cart items in Session, now i want to handle individually Auth user Cart

Here is Cart.php

```
namespace App;


class Cart
{
    public $items=null;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalPrice = 0;

    public function __construct($oldCart)
    {
        if($oldCart){
            $this->items = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
        }
    }

    public function add($item,$id){
        $storedItems = ['qty'=>0,'price'=>$item->price,'item'=>$item];
        if ($this->items){
            if (array_key_exists($id,$this->items)){
                $storedItems = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }
        $storedItems['qty']++;
        $storedItems['price'] = $item->ucp * $storedItems['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItems;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->ucp;
    }

}
```

Here is cart controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Cart;
use App\Models\CartDetail;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function addToCart(Request $request)
    {

        $id = $request->product_id;

        $product = Product::find($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        if ($request->get_quantity) {
            while ($request->get_quantity > 0) {
                $cart->add($product, $product->id);
                $request->get_quantity--;
            }
        } else {
            $cart->add($product, $product->id);
        }

        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);



        return Session::get('cart')->totalQty;


    }

   }
```

Where i am handle auth user? In this scenario when one user add product in cart those item shows to another user as well :( please give a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it unique with userId. Something like below

```
$request->session()->put('cart'.$userId, $cart);
```

when you need to get that cart, get it like below.

```
return Session::get('cart'.$userId)->totalQty;
```

Now let me explain you.

Am just concatenating `userId` with `cart` so it becomes unique. 
when first user is logged in and i need to get his cart. so i simply right below.

```
Session::get('cart'.Auth::id())->totalQty;
```

that's how you will get cart of the related user only.

You can also use some laravel cart package. Let me know if you need one in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks this solution is help for me :)

Comment: Yes, please tell me about laravel package

Comment: if this answer helped you, Please accept it and for cart package you can follow this one https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart